# AWS Logs Insights parse regexp always empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a log string:

```
F, [2021-02-24T09:06:30.428708 #9] FATAL -- : [3c25b3e6-fa19-48c8-93c7-5661dc2ec338]
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/jsonws/invoke"):
```

I want to extract the path */api/jsonws/invoke* as a parsed field with this request:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| limit 300
| parse @message /.*No route matches [[A-Z]{3,7}] "(?<path>.*)".*/
```

I expect to see */api/jsonws/invoke* in the output in column **path**, but instead my path column in the output is always empty.

I've tested the regexp expression with an online tool and it seem to work as I expect. I'm also sure that there are matching logs in the output.

Is there any mistake in my Log Insights query?

Answer (score 0):

Regexp didn't work out, so I ended up doing this:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| parse @message "(No route matches [*] \"*\"):" as method, path
| filter ispresent(path)
| stats count(*) as count by path, method
| sort count desc
```